Docker Build Fails Due to Network Connectivity Issue with Prisma (EAI_AGAIN)
I am experiencing a network connectivity issue while building a Docker image for my Node.js project, which uses Express and Prisma ORM to communicate with a PostgreSQL database. The error occurs specifically at the npx prisma generate step. Below is my Dockerfile:
FROM node:20

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm install
RUN npx prisma generate
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "dist/index.js"]


During the build process, I encounter the following error:
Error: request to https://binaries.prisma.sh/all_commits/34ace0eb2704183d2c05b60b52fba5c43c13f303/debian-openssl-3.0.x/schema-engine.sha256 failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN binaries.prisma.sh


Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

DNS Settings:

Updated Docker daemon's DNS settings to use Google's public DNS servers (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4).
Restarted the Docker service after the changes.


Network Mode:

Enabled Docker BuildKit and used the --network host option during the build process.


Base Image:

Tried different Node.js base images, including node:18-alpine and node:18-slim.


Proxy Check:

Verified that my environment variables do not indicate that I am behind a proxy.


Network Connectivity Test in Temporary Container:

Initial success but subsequent failure in accessing the Alpine package repositories:
docker run --rm -it alpine sh -c "apk add --no-cache curl && curl -I https://binaries.prisma.sh" 

Initial output indicated connectivity:
HTTP/2 404 
date: Mon, 15 Jul 2024 14:57:00 GMT
content-type: text/html
vary: Accept-Encoding
cache-control: max-age=120
cf-cache-status: MISS
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 8a3a9a3adc253b27-BOM

Subsequent attempts failed:
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
WARNING: fetching https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/main: temporary error (try again later)
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
WARNING: fetching https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.20/community: temporary error (try again later)




Manual Dependency Installation:

Manually installed dependencies and generated Prisma client locally, then copied the generated files into the Docker image.
This time the build was successful and when running the container, it worked for the routes which did not use the database, but when there was a need to establish connection to the cloud database, it would fail.


Busybox Container Network Test:

Ran a busybox container to test network connectivity:
docker run --rm busybox ping -c 4 google.com
Output:
PING google.com (142.250.192.78): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 142.250.192.78: seq=0 ttl=254 time=44.824 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.192.78: seq=1 ttl=254 time=44.824 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.192.78: seq=2 ttl=254 time=44.874 ms
64 bytes from 142.250.192.78: seq=3 ttl=254 time=45.367 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 44.824/44.972/45.367 ms




Docker Network Configuration:

Inspected the bridge network configuration:
docker network inspect bridge
Output:
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "1b48727c2e54967fbf86f3d1c68ca36677d24f5792ffb8508dfe4e714aca9611",
        "Created": "2024-07-15T14:46:24.798485127Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]





Additional Information:

Host Machine:

Operating System: Endeavour OS
Kernel:  Linux 6.9.9-arch1-1


Docker Version: 27.0.3
Prisma Version: 5.16.2
Node.js Version: 20.13.1

Questions:

How can I ensure my Docker container has proper network connectivity during the build process?
Are there any additional network configurations I should consider for Docker?
Could there be an issue with the Prisma binary server, and how can I work around it?

Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Request for More Information:
If you need any additional information about my environment or configuration, please let me know, and I will provide it promptly.

I have also tried all the measures in your question and finally found out that my router has DNS proxy enabled , i disabled and enabled the DNS proxy in my routers gateway and the issue was gone.
If you still can't get it working . Connect your machine to your mobile data and I am sure it will work.

Thank you for the reply,
I tried building the image using mobile data and it worked fine. However, even after disabling the DNS status and manually adding primary and secondary DNS to Google's Public DNS: 8.8.8.8 It still did not work. Can you please elaborate more on the process you did to fix this issue on your end?

step 1 what i did was login to my router gateway (198.168.1.1 this is my routers ip address and password was admin and admin)
step 2 was network->DNS->enable/disable
step 3 : step 2 will reset the router and you ad make the docker image just fine
